# List the names of adopters who have adopted more than 3 animals

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are the tables 
Animals

```
(ID: int, Name: varchar(15), PrevOwner: varchar(15), DateAdmitted: date, Type: varchar(15))
```

Adopter

```
(SIN: int, Name: varchar(15), Address: varchar(15), OtherAnimals: int)
```

Adoption

```
(AnimalID: int, SIN: int, AdoptDate: date, chipNo: int)
```

I want to List the names of adopters who have adopted more than 3 animals

This query gives an error:

```
   select distinct Name
   from Adopter, Adoption
   where Adoption.SIN = Adopter.SIN
   GROUP BY Adoption.SIN
   Having count(SIN) > 3;
111
```

Comment: you have to group by the name if that is the field you want to return.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Where do I begin...please learn to just proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!!!  Also please learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  Your query definitely won't run in 99% of dbms.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't join like that... that syntax for joins is over 20 years old.  Use the new syntax

Then if you want names you have to group by names.

Like this:

```
select  Adoption.Name 
from Adopter
join Adoption on Adoption.SIN = Adopter.SIN
GROUP BY Adoption.Name 
Having count(*) > 3;
```

Answer (score -3):

You must to inform the name of table in `HAVING` because the column "SIN" is ambiguous

**Try this:**

```
select distinct Adoption.Name from Adopter,Adoption
   where Adoption.SIN = Adopter.SIN
   GROUP BY Adoption.SIN
   Having count(Adoption.SIN) > 3;
```